# Binding Ui to java interface using UiBinder in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Let's say I have an interface A which is implemented by classes B and C.

```
public class B implements A extends Composite {}
public class C implements A extends Composite {}
```

I created another class D which binds to Ui using UiBinder in GWT.

```
public class D {
  public A widget;
  ...
  // binds to D.ui.xml
  ...
}
```

D.ui.xml

```
 ...
 <A ui:field='widget'>
 ...
```

B and C are widgets that bind to their own ui.xml files and are injected into class D under different conditions.

When I try binding UI to interface A (which is either B or C depending on the binding notation) in class D, I get
"Expecting only widgets"
error which in understandable considering the fact that A doesn't implement Composite or Widget class.

Is there a way to accomplish this behavior, I do not want to create different versions of class D for each behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` could extend `IsWidget`. Also, obviously, make sure your `widget` field is `@UiField(provided=true)`